# Why is my recordset result accessed repeatedly and not cached?

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I have a DAO.Recordest called `products` which I assign like this

```
Set products = db.OpenRecordset("Product URLs for Sitemap")
```

"Product URLs for Sitemap" is a query which when ran makes use of a custom VBA function to populate one of it's columns.

What I am expecting to happen is that `products` will contain the contents of the query after it has ran, like a table. However this does not seem to be the case.

Once I have my `products` recordset I am then looping over it and creating some XML from it

```
Do While Not products.EOF
    Dim prdUrl As String
    Dim prdUpdated As String

    prdUrl = products!url
    prdUpdated = products!updated

    XML = XML & createUrlXml(products!url, products!updated)
    products.MoveNext
Loop
```

However during this loop it is calling the function used in "Product URLs for Sitemap" during each loop. This should only need to be done once - at the time that I populate `products` by calling `Set products = db.OpenRecordset("Product URLs for Sitemap")`

Why is this getting called every time I loop through the `products` recordset and how do I stop this?

Thanks

Comment: Try `db.OpenRecordset("Product URLs for Sitemap", dbOpenSnapshot)` and see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried this and the same thing happens. Previously I was using a QueryDef with the dbOpenSnapshot option but the same thing was happening. I have just tried exactly what you suggested and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried removing `prdUrl` and `prdUpdated` completely and just leaving the `XML = `line and `products.MoveNext` ? It seems that you are requesting `products!url` twice in one loop iteration. which means that `products!url` will move twice.

Comment: How does your 'custom VBA function' look like? Is it possible to execute it just once? Or must it be executed for each row of the recodset? Recodset is not populated after 'Set' was called, you can read it one record after another ... that is the common way to get data out of recordset. Maybe you are are trying to achieve something which is not possible.

Comment: yes, it must be executed on each row. I essentially want an array of objects containing the url and the updated information and I want to get this from a query. Is this really impossible? I don't know VBA very well but with PHP or any other language this would be trivial

Comment: @vba4all that was a mistake on my part while I've been trying to debug it but removing them makes no difference

Comment: Are you saying that your VBA function gets called for every row when the Recordset is first created, and then called *again* for each row as you loop through the Recordset? My testing does not show that.

Comment: @GordThompson yes, that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: If the VBA function is placed in the SQL (as you done), then for EACH row of the query produced, then yes, the function is called, and called independed of each other row. You have to thus ensure "scope" is retained (static or global var). Also, if the output of the query is to a form or report, then just moving the cursor over the window will cause Access to re-request rows. I much suggest you send the resulting query data to a temp table if this is to be used for a report or some such - since re-fresh of the screen can and will often cause the data to be re-queried.

Comment: why don't you call your VBA function from your VBA code?
e.g. Assuming URL is the column with gets calculated then you can use :
prdURL = CreateURL(products!col1, prodicts!col2, ..)

Comment: Is either [url] or [updated] the field that is generated by your VBA function?

Answer (score 2):

How to use GetRows(), simple example:

```
Dim queryText As String
queryText = "SELECT *, YourVBAFunc([URLs_SOURCE]) AS URL FROM Table1;"

Dim products As DAO.Recordset
Set products = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(queryText)

products.MoveLast
products.MoveFirst

Dim data As Variant
data = products.GetRows(products.RecordCount)

' then all data are in the array 'data' ...
```

More information here: 
http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/789969-retrieving-data-dao-recordset-using-getrows

Comment: I am about to try this. Can I ask why you suggest `products.MoveLast`, `products.MoveFirst`?

Comment: it is sometimes necessary for a valid Record Count :-)

Comment: I'm sorry...30 seconds after asking this I discovered this in the link you provided :)

Comment: No problem. Here another usefull link: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-vba-recordset-objects/ ... watch #4

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest turning the query "Product URLs for Sitemap" into a table, which will then force the execution of the function for all rows at that time. So:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB ... yourFunction(args) 
INTO newTableName
FROM tableSpecification
```

Then your loop will not execute the function each iteration.

If this information is going to change (as I'm guessing) drop it after you're done with it, and recreate next time this logic needs to run.

If the data needs to be user- or session- specific, you can generate a random number for the tablename using the timer:

```
newTableName = "myTableName" + replace(Timer,".","")
```

Hope this suggestion helps.