# Why is accessing a DAO.RecordSet so slow compared to running a query?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to solve a more complex problem than this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013790/why-is-my-recordset-result-accessed-repeatedly-and-not-cached)) so I created a simple function to help me troubleshoot:

```
Sub GetRowsTest(x As Integer, y As Integer)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim recordSet As DAO.recordSet
    Dim result As Variant

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set recordSet = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Products", dbOpenSnapshot)

    recordSet.MoveLast
    recordSet.MoveFirst

    result = recordSet.GetRows(10)

    recordSet.Close

    Debug.Print (result(x, y))
End Sub
```

If I run the query "SELECT * FROM Products" in Access it takes about 2 seconds to run and returns 6970 results. When I run the code I have shown above it takes about 5 minutes.

Why is `recordSet.GetRows(10)` slow?

Comment: Just tested it on my system with 9000 Products ( 109 colums ) and it took < 2 secs, mostly for RecordSet.MoveLast.
"Products" is a local table in Access 2010 ??

Comment: What about using ADO?

Comment: Looking at your other post I can see that Products isnt really a table. Accordingly I would expect that the "recordset.MoveLast" is what is chewing up the time. I'll add an answer to that question.

Comment: if you don't care about total records, why movelast and movefirst and then only 10 rows? if you only need 10 rows why don't you alter your SQL command, either with a where condition or limit condition? just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the recordset type from dbOpenSnapshot to dbOpenDynaset and see if that helps.